# Roboguice CreationException in test

Tags: android, unit-testing, roboguice

I'm new to Roboguice topic... 
I'm trying to correctly instantiate the injector inside the Application.onCreate() method. 
I tried in two ways:

1. `RoboGuice.overrideApplicationInjector(this,
   RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this),
                   new SettingsModule());`
2. `RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(this,
   RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, Modules.override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this)).with(new SettingsModule()));`

When running one of the AndroidTestCase I have I ended up with two different results depending on if I used 1 or 2:

1. worked correctly
2. thrown a `com.google.inject.CreationException` for this specific reason:

> Could not find a suitable constructor in
>   my.package.SharedPreferencesStorage. Classes must have either one (and
>   only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument
>   constructor that is not private.

The problem is that SharedPreferencesStorage **has** only one constructor annotated with @Inject, so the exception is quite misleading.

At this point I could go on using the `overrideApplicationInjector()` in my Application but according to the documentation it should be used only in testing. Is it correct? Is there some implication on using it outside a testing class?
Why `getOnCreateBaseApplicationInjector()` doesn't work instead?
Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: were you able to figure this out @Noya?